# Close multiple activities on stack

Tags: java, android

Found lots of similar questions but none that suited my situation.

Basically I have an Android app that flows like so:

```
HOME >> CHECKOUT 1 >> CHECKOUT 2 >> CONFIRMATION PAGE
```

Once we get to the confirmation page I want to 'finish' both checkout pages as I don't want the user seeing orders that have been submitted if they were to hit the back button. I know how to finish the Checkout 2 page once I confirm the order but I don't know how to 'cascade' down the stack to finish both.

When the user hits Back on the confirmation page they should go to the Home screen. I know how to do this with Intents but that's no good for the back button. Unless I override the back button behaviour and do something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I feel like this is very hacky. Anyone know the proper way to do it? Some sort of session variable that `Checkout1.onResume` looks for maybe?

Cheers

Comment: use startActivityForResult, back button will trigger a RESULT_CANCEL result code, which you can use to in turn close your activities.

Comment: How would that work?

Say Checkout 1 starts Checkout 2 using startActivityForResult, and Checkout 2 does the same for Confirmation Page. Then when the user hits back on Confirmation Page I can have Checkout 2 detect the cancel signal and close itself and also send back the cancel signal to Checkout 1 which can close itself.

But what if the user is just on Checkout 2 and hits back? In that scenario I want to just return to Checkout 1 (user might want to change something). Or am I missing something?

Comment: what you can do is in checkout2, in onActivityResult, detect the cancel from confirmation, use `setResult` to assign a dedicated code, and test for this code in checkout1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just overriding the `onBackPressed` method and using doing this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

I'll wait a while before marking the answer in case someone has a better way.